# Genexus 17 no inicia a compilar

Tags: genexus

Al hacer cualquier tipo de build en Genexus 17 con Java no inicia la etapa de compilacion
Se queda frezado antes.
Se probo borrar las carpetas de usuario, los ari, la carpeta compile.
Hay alguna solucion??

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
========== Target Environment update started ==========
Success: Target Environment update
Building changed objects list
No objects to Specify
Generating Resources...Success
========== Default (Java Web) Generation started ==========
Generating to JavaWeb\web\gxcfg.js
Generating to JavaWeb\web\com\metriveerp\GXcfg.java
Generating to JavaWeb\web\com\metriveerp\client.cfg
Generating to JavaWeb\web\web.xml
Generating to JavaWeb\web\bld12.info
Success: Default (Java Web) Generation
Compressing static files...Success
```

Comment: De pronto puedes habilitar el LOG del IDE a ver si en el mismo aparece más información de lo que está pasando (tools/options/trace, más info: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?23257,GeneXus%20Log) 

Un dato relevante también es si tienes habilitados varios especificadores/generadores (https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?25808,Multiple%20Concurrent%20Generator%20and%20Specifier%20Instances)

Comment: Gracias voy a ver que dice el log gracias por la información
El tema de la cantidad de generadores y especificadores ya probe todas las combinaciones posibles y no hubo suerte

Comment: No tendras algo que tranque los procesos? algun antivirus? en el task manager podes ver al proceso funcionando ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pude solucionarlo, la carpeta de la webapp del tomcat no tenia permisos de escritura. El error no salio nunca, ni en los logs. Lo encontre de casualidad el problema.